# Test if mysqli database connection is alive in max 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I just tried a whole lot a things to do something really simple. I would like to test if a mysqli database connection is alive but in maximum 5 seconds. Just to check: *"Hey, are you alive? Good. Continue with the code as quickly as possible."*

So far `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` has not worked for me. The server keeps waiting for +30 seconds and finally throws an error because it had to wait so long. I never intended to have it wait so long. Just check in max 5 seconds if the database is there. Otherwise return false.

This is what I got so far. Again, it waits way too long. The setting seems to be ignored about waiting only 2 seconds.

```
private function _is_db_connection_alive() {
    ini_set( 'mysql.connect_timeout', 2 );

    $link = mysqli_init();
    $link->options( MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 2 );
    $result = @$link->real_connect( GA_DB_HOST, GA_DB_USER, GA_DB_PASSWORD, GA_DB_NAME );

    return $result;
}
```

So, how should this 'testing of the connection' be programmed? Thanks.

Comment: By the way or you running this code on windows or linux server? And which PHP version do you run? .. Because `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  connection timeout in seconds (supported on Windows with TCP/IP since PHP 5.3.1)`

Comment: "Just to check: "Hey, are you alive? Good. Continue with the code as quickly as possible."" i wonder why you would allow continue the PHP code execution i assume the rest of the page is dependent on data from MySQL

Comment: I would have upvoted this if you hadn't set the max_execution_time to the same interval as the socket settings - that was a bit silly. How are you testing this? If you are using a dummy hostname then the delay will be mostly DNS time, not socket connection. You need to point it at a valid address which will drop the packets (or take a very long time to respond).

Comment: @RaymondNijland well, if the connection fails it just displays a message on the pages that the agenda items aren't available. The rest of the website depends on a Worpress database but the events are stored in an external database on another server.

Comment: "if the connection fails it just displays a message on the pages that the agenda items aren't available" How often does a connection to MySQL fail anyway? i wonder if programming a faster error displaying method justifies the time needed to program this for the couple of times MySQL connection is down.